# Why doesn't gplot2::labs() overwrite/update the name argument of scales functions (i.e. ggplot2::scale_*_(name =))?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Context:** sometimes I need to change only the labels of a plot (*e.g.* to change the language) but I do not want to make the whole plot again as the code might be very long in some cases.

**Problem:** they are at least two ways to define the aesthetics labels:

1. With the function `ggpot2::labs(x = ..., y = ...)` and,
2. With the `name` argument of the scales functions `ggplots::scale_*_*(name = ...)`

According to the example below, it seems that, for a plot `p`, `p + labs()` can overwrite labs defined with the `labs()` function but not labs defined with `scale_*_*(name = ...)`.

**Question:** How to avoid this behavior? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Example:**

This is working as intended:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# This is working as expected
p1 <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Width)) +
  scale_x_continuous() +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  labs(x = "A name",
       y = "Another name")
p1
```

```r
# trying to change the labs without making the plot again
p1 + labs(
  x = "The new x title",
  y = "The new y title"
)
```

While this does not:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# This is not working
p2 <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Width)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "A name") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Another name")
p2
```

```r
p2 + labs(
  x = "The new x title",
  y = "The nex y title"
)
```

Comment: Interesting. Although I don't really see a problem with this (just define your names in the labs layer), I don't think that this is intended behaviour. By the way, the order of the layers doesn't matter: the labs layer is also overwritten when called before the scale function

Comment: @tjebo, I like the use of `labs()` because I find it very easy to use to quickly change labels. In addition, if I use `p + scale_*_*(name = ...)` just to replace the label of the axis, it will crush all the other arguments and print the warning: "Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale". Thus, it is needed to write again all the scale arguments.

Comment: I like to use labs as well for convenience sake (and it seems also to avoid problems as the herein described). Of course, a second same scale function will overwrite the first one, and I personally would feel should be avoided.

Comment: @tjebo well your comment feels like the best thing to do! Maybe it will lead to other questions in case of complex aes settings that rely on the `name` argument but I cannot find an example right now.

Comment: As I find this curious enough, I filed an issue report. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just explaining what is happening. There are multiple ways to set labels in a plot, which take different priorities. Here are the priorities from highest to lowest.

(0. In some scale extensions, the `make_title()` method can be overwritten. This generally doesn't apply to the vast majority of scales though. I know of exactly 0 such scales, but it is a theoretical possibility.)

1. The guide title.
2. The scale name.
3. The `labs()` function.
4. The captured expression in `aes()`.

Most of the disambiguation happens in [this line](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/e0d54f6d2be6452bbab61a5018abc231a3172ca6/R/guides-.r#L223) of ggplot2 source code, where priorities 1-3 are resolved. What the `labs()` function in essence does is to override the automatically generated label from the captured expression, thereby giving (3) precedence over (4).

Try commenting out some parts of the plot below to double check yourself.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris
names(df)[1] <- "Last Priority"

ggplot(df, aes(`Last Priority`, Sepal.Width)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name  = "Second Priority",
    guide = guide_axis(title = "First priority")
  ) +
  labs(x = "Third Priority")
```

So your best bet to override the title for the x-axis is to use:

```r
plot + guides(x = guide_axis(title = "My new title"))
```

Since the axis guide is typically `guide_axis()` or `guide_none()`, you have a decent chance of this working most of the time (except when the plot doesn't have an axis). Moreover, if you have a function generating a plot with a predefined scale for x, this should be fine (unless they set specific options in the guide).

Comment: Many thanks for this insight on label priorities, until today I was thinking that the last function call had the final word.

Comment: very interesting. I've also closed my "issue" on GitHub linking to this splendid explanation. Thanks!